# how make a subfolder in google-drive after execution this script folder make in root

Tags: php, google-drive-api

how make a subfolder in google-drive 
after execution this script folder make in root

```
enter code here
$parentId=$par_idpath;
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle($dir_name);  
$mimeType= gdrive_files::$mime_types['folder'];
$file->setMimeType($mimeType);
// Set the parent folder.
if ($parentId ) 
{
$parent = new Google_ParentReference();
$parent->setId($parentId);
$file->setParents(array($parent));
}
try {
$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
  'mimeType' => $mimeType,
));
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $this->err=$e->getMessage();
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/folder According to this a folder is a flie with no extension with it so can trying by inserting a file under the root folder id

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you simply have to make sure that `$parentId` contains the id of the folder you want the subfolder to be contained in.

Answer (score 0):

As @Claudio Cherubino said, you can specify a parent id. Since you want your subolder to be inside your new folder. You can use the id of the created `$createdFile`.

So I guess running your code again, setting `$parentId = $createdFile->id;`. Would do the trick.